# ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "C63657128981248445" in application

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm encountering an issue with oracle apex when using a cascading LOV in a Interactive Grid. The page and LOVs work fine if I don't make the list as a cascading LOV. When I attempt to use the cascading LOV I want to use I'm met with:

[image: Error Message]

From reading on forums the common cause has to do with the component not existing; however, the component message is referring to the application page that the LOV is on. I don't have any issues with this page when I remove the cascading LOV in question. I have been able to create other cascading LOVs on the page and have them perform correctly. The issue is only present when using cascading LOVs with the Interactive Grid. (NOTE: I'm currently using pop-up LOV, but have the issue with select lists as well).

[image: Application Page - Application Dashboard]

I'm stumped, if anyone has any idea what might be happening let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching I was able to find an answer to my own question: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4012955

As stated in the link above this is a bug with the oracle apex software and should now be fixed in 5.1.2

I would test to see for myself but as my company is the one that owns the install I cannot upgrade to confirm the issue has been resolved.

Comment: 5.1.2 is now confirmed to have fixed the issue